# Horizontal Schedule Bar for Website

Tags: html, css

I am working on a personal website and so far, everything has been going pretty well. I got the pages set up with the basic layout and everything like that. Now I am trying to make it look more professional. I bowl in tournaments multiple weekends a month. (Yes, I said bowl and yes I do consider it a sport) What I would like to do is put a schedule type bar across the top. (example can be found by clicking the link in this post) The problem is I cannot find any tutorials on how to do this because I don't really know what this functionality is called. Everything that I have tried searching for has just brought up horizontal navigation/scroll bars. Can anyone point me to a tutorial or give me a starting point for getting something like this working on my website?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What server side language will you be using?

Comment: I know javascript and c#. First thing I tried was using a table, but I couldn't get it to look professional. It just looked, well...like a table. I also tried modifying a horizontal navigation menu, but again, just can't get it to look clean and professional like the one in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is actually a slider, showing like 15 slides at a time.

[BX SLIDER](http://bxslider.com/) - jQuery Slider

The slider included above has many options that let you customize how it works, such as

- maxSlides - the total number of slides shown at a given time ( you'd set to 15 )
- moveSlides - the number of slides to move on change ( you'd set to 1 ).

Example JS

```
$('.schedule').bxSlider({
   maxSlides: 15,
   minSlides: 15,       
   moveSlides: 1,
   autoStart: false
});
```

Your HTML, with the schedule and all, as styled as you would like, is contained in a list.

```
<ul class="schedule">
    <li>January 15th - Match</li>
    <li>January 22nd - Match</li>
    <li>January 23rd - Match</li>
</ul>
```

etc etc etc.

Comment: awesome! Thank you. I'm going to start looking into this and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: This looks like it will do exactly what I am looking for!